# Finding a SQL Server Assembly: Where is "100" folder in the installation folder in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server

I need this assembly `Microsoft.SqlServer.RuntimeWrapper.dll` and it is not in `<drive>:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly`. I have SQL Server 2019 installed (Developer Edition).
According to this page [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-programming-overview?view=sql-server-ver15#locating-assemblies) the assemblies should also be in this folder: `<drive>:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies.` But on my computer I do not have the 100 folder. There are 80, 90, 110, 130, 150, Client SDK and MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER. I think I have checked the relevant boxes when choosing features.

How can I get hold of `Microsoft.SqlServer.RuntimeWrapper.dll`?

Thanks.

Edit: Both of these PowerShell searches to not give any hits. I have also tried these searched on production servers with SQL Server and Integration Services installed and no hits:

```
Get-ChildItem "$env:SystemRoot\Microsoft.NET\"  -Filter *RuntimeWrapper.dll -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Ignore
Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\" -Filter *Wrapper.dll -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Ignore
```

Edit: On my SQL Server installation the following are installed:
[image]

Extention for SSIS:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you have installed `Install Integration Services (SSIS)`? This might help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/install-integration-services?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @SqlWorldWide: I tried to choose as much as possible with SSIS. Don't remember the choices now, but quite sure everything with SSIS was chosen.

Comment: I added a link to my initial comment which might help.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide: Please see screenshot. But it is strange that I cannot unselect features and I can only add more. Is that normal?

Comment: "<drive>:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies". This path seems old. Try to look into 130 , 140 or 150 folders

Comment: @MBuschi: See the PowerShell search. It does not give any hits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's a doc [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/7408).  That's the Primary Interop Assembly, so it's not really *part* of SSIS.  And it's installed as part of the Visual Studio tools.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have Visual Studio Proffesional. And it is not there. What do I need to choose in the Visual Studio Installer?

Comment: Did you install the "SQL Server Integration Services Projects" Visual Studio Extension?

Comment: Yes it is installed, see screenshot in the question.

Comment: I am trying to uninstall the extension and install it again.

Comment: Now I have uninstalled and installed the extension and still no hits with `Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\" -Filter *RuntimeWrapper.dll -Recurse -Force `

Comment: It's actually called "DTSRuntimeWrap.dll"

Comment: Thanks found it. So actaully it is also in GAC it seems when I search in `C:\``

Comment: Now I can locate many, but only one 64 bit which only covers to sql server 2017. This dll is also in App32 folder now but not in App64. Seems the extension is 32 bit...? How can I get hold of the 64 bit for sql server 2019?

Comment: It might be AnyCPU, as it’s just the PIA.

Comment: But I cannot load the 32 bit ones in PowerShell and I get an error. And I don't now if the issue I have is because of the problem with the lacking of sql server 2019

Comment: I can load and use that from both 32bit and 64bit programs.  If you're having an issue in powershell, add some sample code and the error to your question.

Comment: hi can you please look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71510337/powershell-not-guessing-net-type-correctly?noredirect=1#comment126434593_71510337

Comment: Hi David, did you have time to look at the question from my previous comment?